# Get both sides of a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2 app. In this app I have setup a polymorphic association between
a subscription model and a backend_user model.

In BackendUser model I got this:

```
has_one :subscription, as: :subscribable
```

In Subscription model I got this:

```
belongs_to :backend_user, polymorphic: true
```

If I want to retrieve the subscription for a backend_user I do this and it works fine:

```
user = BackendUser.find(1)
user.subscription
```

What I also want to do is turn the tables. I want to get the backend_user for a subscription
like this but I get nil back.

```
sub = Subscription.find(1)
sub.backend_user
```

I got this in the subscriptions table:

```
t.integer  "subscribable_id"
t.string   "subscribable_type"
```

How can I get the backend user object for the subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
sub = Subscription.find(1)
sub.subscribable
```

That will give you backend user object.